# Android touch event handling from DDMS

Tags: android, events, touch, ddms, ontouchlistener

Anyone knows if there is a way to add touch events to the DDMS emulator control? Unfortunately i have no real device and i want to make some experiments over the touch events on a AVD 2.3.3 device.

Comment: you can use your mouse to create (single digit) touch evets. also the emulator isn't very good. the few $ that an old testing device will set you back will be really worth it in time and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your ontouch method:

```
...
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
sb.setLength(0);
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
builder.append("down, ");
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
builder.append("move, ");
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
builder.append("cancel", ");
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
builder.append("up, ");
break;
}
builder.append(event.getX());
builder.append(", ");
builder.append(event.getY());
String text = builder.toString();
Log.d("TouchTest", text);

return true;

}
```